# Angular $http changing url on Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, http, url, devise

This is my first ever stack overflow question because google usually sorts me out. However I can't seem to find anything/anyone online replicating my issue.

I'm using the [Angular Devise](https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise) module and when I attempt a login with the following URL

test.aam.tunnel.logicsaas-development.com:3000/users/sign_in.json

$http or Devise changes it to

http://undefined:undefinedtest.aam.tunnel.logicsaas-development.com:3000/users/sign_in.json

here is my config code:

```
AuthInterceptProvider.interceptAuth(true);

AuthProvider.loginPath('test.aam.tunnel.logicsaas-development.com:3000/users/sign_in.json');
AuthProvider.loginMethod('POST');
AuthProvider.resourceName('users');
```

And my login call:

```
var credentials = {
    email: 'user@domain.com',
    password: 'password1'
};

Auth.login(credentials).then(function(user) {
    console.log(user); // => {id: 1, ect: '...'}
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
    // Authentication failed...
});
```

I dug into devise and im 99% sure this is happening with $http. Any help at all would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must change your host configuration with something like this:

```js
.config(function(AuthProvider){
  AuthProvider.baseUrl("http://test.aam.tunnel.logicsaas-development.com:3000");
})
```